# How to use setFieldValue in <Formik>?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I don't fully understand the difference between `<Formik/>` and `useFormik()` implementation. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Is it possible to use `formik.setFieldValue()` with `<Formik />`? I need to set the value in the async callback.

If so, can you please share a snippet on how to do this. TIA

Comment: I updated this example in codesandbox please check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-owxvo?file=/index.js

Answer (score 2):

In any children component of formik, you can use the hook `useFormikContext`, which return all data you got in render props on a formik. so:

```
const {setFieldValue} = useFormikContext();
```

also, you can use hook to get stuuf for specific field, using `useField`:

```
const [fieldInput, fieldMeta, fieldHelpers] = useField('fieldName');
fieldHelpers.setValue(value);
```

Note that you must to be in inner component. not same component where you define the Formik component, but one of its childs

Answer (score 1):

[image]
here is the screenshot of that piece of code

Comment: thanks  for sharing  your code.  How about using setFieldValue outside `<Formik>`? I need to use it for async callback.

Comment: You can use a function only inside Formik.

Comment: @AlexeyKorkoza thanks, if that's the case, I'll just  implement useFormik(). Now i have to refactor the form... sigh,...

Comment: yes for that implement `useFormik()`