# Accessing value of child component within Formik form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I have a form that uses Formik and contains two fields - `email` and `siteID`

The `email` field uses a `TextInput` whereas `siteID` comes from my own component called `DropDown` that uses `react-native-dropdown-picker`

When my form is submitted I can see the value of `email` within `handleSubmit()` but `siteID` remains as 0 and not the selected value.

How can I access the selected value from my `DropDown` child component when submitting the parent form?

### My form

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
      <Formik
        validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
        initialValues={{
          siteID: 0,
          email: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
      >
        {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          errors,
          isValid,
        }) => (
          <>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Email</Text>
            <TextInput
              name="email"
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
              onBlur={handleBlur("email")}
              value={values.email}
              keyboardType="email-address"
            />

            <DropDown name="siteID" />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

### DropDown component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import {usePostRequest} from '../../client';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const DropDown = () => {
  const [pickeropen, pickersetOpen] = useState(false);
  const [pickervalue, pickersetValue] = useState(null);
  const [pickeritems, pickersetItems] = useState([]);

  const {status: siteStatus, data: siteData} = usePostRequest('/api/sites', {});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('siteData', siteData);
    if (siteData.count) {
      const sitesList = [];
      siteData.results.map((item, key) =>
        sitesList.push({label: item.siteName, value: item.siteID})
      );
      pickersetItems(sitesList);
    }
  }, [siteData]);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder="Please chose a site"
      open={pickeropen}
      value={pickervalue}
      items={pickeritems}
      setOpen={pickersetOpen}
      setValue={pickersetValue}
      setItems={pickersetItems}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setFieldValue](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void) provided by Formik to set a field manually.

A good example of usage is provided in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70844508/14900930)

You can pass setFieldValue to your DropDown Component:

```js
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
      <Formik
        validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
        initialValues={{
          siteID: 0,
          email: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
      >
        {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          errors,
          isValid,
          setFieldValue,
        }) => (
          <>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Email</Text>
            <TextInput
              name="email"
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
              onBlur={handleBlur("email")}
              value={values.email}
              keyboardType="email-address"
            />

            <DropDown name="siteID" setSiteID={setFieldValue} />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

And trigger it from inside of the DropDown Component:

```js
const DropDown = ({ setSiteID }) => {
  const [pickeropen, pickersetOpen] = useState(false);
  const [pickervalue, pickersetValue] = useState(null);
  const [pickeritems, pickersetItems] = useState([]);

  const {status: siteStatus, data: siteData} = usePostRequest('/api/sites', {});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('siteData', siteData);
    if (siteData.count) {
      const sitesList = [];
      siteData.results.map((item, key) =>
        sitesList.push({label: item.siteName, value: item.siteID})
      );
      pickersetItems(sitesList);
    }
  }, [siteData]);
  
  // You can use useEffect or create a custom handleValueChange 
  // and pass it to DropDownPicker
  useEffect(() =>  {
    setSiteID('siteID', pickervalue);
  }, [pickersetValue])

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder="Please chose a site"
      open={pickeropen}
      value={pickervalue}
      items={pickeritems}
      setOpen={pickersetOpen}
      setValue={pickersetValue}
      setItems={pickersetItems}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Great, this works. FYI, I had to change pickersetValue to pickervalue within the useEffect I have added to my DropDown component

Comment: Ah yeah, a great catch, that's a mistake on my part, I will edit the answer. 
And glad that helped you :)

Comment: This works, but there is no reason not to use a `Field` here. That removes the need to synchronize picker value with form state via `useEffect` which adds an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: Yes totally agree, your approach is also good, I've also specified a comment on top of useEffect to use a custom handler for valueChange. The reason why I used useEffect as the primary solution, is because of the reusability of the DropDownPicker Component, passing an onChange or custom handler to setValue on DropDownPicker will require modifying the component itself.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the docs, to use your own component, you should wrap your component in a `Field` as follows:

```
const DropDownField = <Field name="siteId" component={DropDown} />
```

When using a `Field` formik will inject props (name, value, onChange, onBlur) into your component allowing you to control the form state.

So you can then redeclare your component with those props as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import {usePostRequest} from '../../client';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const DropDown = ({ field: { name, value, onChange }) => {
  const [pickeropen, pickersetOpen] = useState(false);
  const [pickeritems, pickersetItems] = useState([]);

  const {status: siteStatus, data: siteData} = usePostRequest('/api/sites', {});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('siteData', siteData);
    if (siteData.count) {
      const sitesList = [];
      siteData.results.map((item, key) =>
        sitesList.push({label: item.siteName, value: item.siteID})
      );
      pickersetItems(sitesList);
    }
  }, [siteData]);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder="Please chose a site"
      open={pickeropen}
      value={value}
      items={pickeritems}
      setOpen={pickersetOpen}
      setValue={onChange}
      setItems={pickersetItems}
      name={name}
    />
  );
};
```

Essentially you wire your component up to the `onChange` and `value` props. Since you assigned a `name` of siteId to the `DropDownField` component (which you should now use in your form), any time you call `onChange` site Id will update.

[Link to docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/field)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although the other answers might work, you lose the benefits of using formik.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

get `setFieldValue` from formik props.

add onChangeDropdown to `<Dropdown />` like,

> <DropDown name="siteID" onChangeDropdown={(value)=>{
> setFieldValue("siteID",value)
> }}/>

get the props inside Dropdown component,

> const DropDown = (props) => {

add `onChangeValue` prop to your DropDownPicker

> onChangeValue={props.onChangeDropdown}